# How to remove Stopwords from CSV file using NLTK?

Tags: python, csv, nltk, tokenize, data-cleaning

Trying to remove stopwords from csv file that has 3 columns and creates a new csv file with the removed stopwords. This is successful however, the data in the new file appears across the top row rather than the columns in the original file.

```
    import io 
    import codecs
    import csv
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
    file1 = codecs.open('soccer.csv','r','utf-8') 
    line = file1.read() 
    words = line.split()
    for r in words: 
        if not r in stop_words: 
            appendFile = open('stopwords_soccer.csv','a', encoding='utf-8') 
            appendFile.write(" "+r)
            appendFile.close()
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the first 10 lines of the .csv files.

Comment: @Gardener What would be the best way to do this, sorry im new to all of this

Comment: What should the new csv contain? For example if there is a stopword in the second column of the original csv, what is the corresponding output? All three columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert a newline character after writing each line.

```
for r in words: 
    if not r in stop_words: 
        appendFile = open('stopwords_soccer.csv','a', encoding='utf-8') 
        appendFile.write(r)
        appendFile.write("\n")
        appendFile.close()
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, this has stopped the initial issue but now columns are mixed and all over the place. I don't know if there's a way to share some of the .csv file

Comment: @plshelpme_ That is very much possible depending on how your CSV file is ordered.    For example if by the process of removing stop words you delete some values for a column, then the final result could very well be jumbled. It would be better if you are to work on pandas Dataframes instead of reading from and writing to files.

Comment: @omkar Thanks for the advice, used pandas and was successful